# Limit of $\large{\frac{1}{2^x}}$ as $x \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

Limit of  $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^x}$$

Is there way i was just told $lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1$, $lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$

Hence it's zero? I'm confused. Why didn't i just divide everything by something, like on simpler limit question $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{5x^2}{x^2+5}=1$?

Comment: that doesn't make any sense, $n$ is independent of $x$ and so the answer is still $\frac{1}{2^n}$ unless you made a mistake

Comment: This question needs serious editing by the author to make the intent clear.

Comment: Sorry the font was really small and id idn't notice it's meant to be 2^x

Answer (score 1):

Your notation is a bit confusing since you used $f(x)$ twice to refer to (I assume) $1$ and $2^n$ as the numerator and denominator of the function.

The logic behind what you were just told is that as $n$ goes towards infinity, the denominator of the function will keep going up (towards infinity) while the numerator will remain constant. If the denominator keeps getting bigger without bound, and the numerator stays constant, the value of the fraction will decrease. Hence, the limit of $\frac{1}{2^n}$ as $n$ goes to infinity will be 0, because the fraction will keep decreasing. It is interesting to note that the limit you are searching and the limit of $\frac{1}{n}$ as $n$ approaches infinity in this case are exactly the same question: even though the former approaches infinity much faster, they both tend to infinity, the fractions will tend to $\frac{1}{\infty}$, and the value of the fraction will tend towards 0.

What did you mean by dividing everything by something like simpler limits? Which limits have you learned?

Comment: You know $\lim_{x \to \infty} $\frac{1}{n^2+2}$ you divide everything by $n^2$ and find that 1 and 2 become zero so the numerator is zero and hence limit is zero

Comment: I didn't word well but i meant like this  $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{5x^2}{x^2+5}=1$?

Comment: The biggest difference is that the two examples you commented used polynomials which act differently from exponentials. Because of this difference, the tricks don't always apply.

Also the limit you commented has a value of 5

One thing to note is that the exponents always grow faster than polynomials, that is, $\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{2^x}{x^{100000}}} = \infty$, if the number being exponentiated is bigger than 1.